# How to calculate ratio of two values in the table for specific key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following table

[image]

How can I get ratio values ?

The ratio between the values in the "Value" column, the sum is always 1 as 100%.

[image]

the number of rows in the table is not limited, there can be more Number1, Number2, Code combinations.

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95fc1

Comment: Please imagine we are all outside of your head and can't don't know what ratio you are talking about...

Comment: Its the Ratio between the two values, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Number1, Number2, 
       [Ratio]  / (SUM([Ratio]) OVER (PARTITION BY Number1, Number2) * 1.0)
FROM Example
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/CRJ16503)